# How to let Fragment do some action before onBackPressed() kill it

Tags: android, onbackpressed

I wonder if this is possible to do in `AppCompatActivity`. I want to let top most `Fragment` do some action before `AppCompatActivity` `super.onBackPressed();` kill `Fragment`

Here´s the mockup code which speaks for itself:

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  ToppMosteFragment.doSomeActionBeforeBackPressedKillYou();
  final Handler handler = new Handler();
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           // this is not working..
           super.onBackPressed();
        }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to make `doSomeActionBeforeBackPressedKillYou()` return a boolean

and do

```
 @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if(ToppMosteFragment.doSomeActionBeforeBackPressedKillYou()) {
      super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```

EDIT:

If you defined the animation , you can add a listener  :

```
    Animation animation = actionButton.getHideAnimation();

    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
        }           
        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
        }           
        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
            listener.onFabAnimationEnd();
        }
    });

    actionButton.setHideAnimation(animation);
```

listener is a interface that is implement by your activity class

And in you activity

```
@Override
public void onFabAnimationEnd() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Yes that would work but I use [the fab](https://github.com/Scalified/fab) That has this `actionButton.playHideAnimation();` that apparently does the work asynchronous (hiding the fab button). Would be grate to get a second delay to show the hiding animation

Comment: Animation are defined by you or there are by default in the lib ?

Comment: thanks not sure but I I just [requested issue](https://github.com/Scalified/fab/issues/46) about this to add playHideAnimationCompleationListner

Comment: I think Animation is in the lib for sure

Comment: You can set the same animation too with actionButton.setHideAnimation(animation)

Comment: The animation is ActionButton.Animations could not see how to propagate the underling `android.view.animation.Animation ` to attache a an `setAnimationListener`. Maybe I must fork the lib and create a pull request with this enhancement

Comment: Accordint to the lib there is a getShowAnimation()/getHideAnimation(), maybe you can use these like in my edit

Comment: yes your right...:) The `onAnimationEnd` can be exposed thanks now just must fit this to work :)

Comment: In the  `public void onBackPressed()`  The `super.onBackPressed();` cannot run Inside  `public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)` it gives `cannot resolve method onBackPressed()` . Maybe need to create field that hold activity..hmm

Comment: Yes normal behavior `onAnimationEnd()` is on `AnimationListener` so these not the context of the activity. Yes a activy field should work.

Comment: my God you're a genius with `ActivityMain.super.onBackPressed();` it works. There´s a smooth ` actionButton.playHideAnimation()`  now before frag die, thanks a bunch  Cochi

Comment: I'm glad I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

I got an Idea,
This could be an universal thing -

Create `BaseFragment` having the method like below -

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

    public boolean onFragmentBackPressed() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

extend your `MyFragment` to `BaseFragment`

```
class MyFragment extends BaseFragment {
   // override method
   @Override
    public boolean onFragmentBackPressed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Check in your `MainActivity` that if `BaseFragment` method `onFragmentBackPressed()` if returning false or what, if yes - perform some action before exiting

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (MyFragment instance if BaseFragment) {
      if (!((BaseFragment) MyFragment).onFragmentBackPressed()) {
          // perform and action
     } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
     }
  } else {
      super.onBackPressed();
  }
}
```